# Остаётся ли предыдущий объект в памяти при создании нового?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что происходит с предыдущим объектом при создании нового при выполнении данного кода? Остаётся ли он в памяти?

```
import time


class AnyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def any_req():
        return True  # Тут допустим какой-нибудь api request


while True:
    req = AnyClass().any_req() # Можно вызвать и не создавая экземпляр класса, но интересует поведение именно при создании
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/336156/

Comment: Определите в классе метод `__del__` с выводом, и вы увидите, что объект удаляется.